# R text mining: Create document term matrix from dataframe, convert to dataframe, retain columns from original dataframe

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, tm

Thanks to lawyeR for recommending the tidytext package. Here is some code based on that package that seems to work pretty well on my sample data. It doesn't work quite so well though when the value of the text column is blank. (There are times when this will happen and it will make sense to keep the blank rather than filtering it.)  I've set the first observation for TVAR to a blank to illustrate. The code drops this observation. How can I get R to keep the observation and to set the frequencies for each word to zero? I tried some ifelse statements using and not using the pipe. It's not working so well though. The troulbe seems to center around the unnest_tokens function from the tidytext package.

```
sampletxt$TVAR[1] <- ""
```

chunk_words <- sampletxt %>%

group_by(PTNO, DATE, TYPE) %>%

unnest_tokens(word, TVAR, to_lower = FALSE) %>%

count(word) %>%

spread(word, n, 0)

I have an R data frame. I want to use it to create a document term matrix. Presumably I would want to use the tm package to do that but there might be other ways. I then want to convert that matrix back to a data frame. I want the final data frame to contain identifying variables from the original data frame.

Question is, how do I do that? I found some answers to a similar question, but that was for a data frame with text and a single ID variable. My data are likely to have about half a dozen variables that identify a given text record. So far, attempts to scale up the solution for a single ID variable haven't proven all that successful.

Below are some sample data. I created these for another task which I did manage to solve.

How can I get a version of this data frame that has an additional frequency column for each word in the text entries and that retains variables like PTNO, DATE, and TYPE?

```
sampletxt <-
```

structure(

```
list(

  PTNO = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3),

  DATE = structure(c(16801, 16436, 16436, 16832, 16845), class = "Date"),

  TYPE = c(

    "Progress note",

    "Progress note",

    "CAT scan",

    "Progress note",

    "Progress note"

  ),

  TVAR = c(

    "This sentence contains the word metastatic and the word Breast plus the phrase denies any symptoms referable to.",

    "This sentence contains tnm code T-1, N-O, M-0. This sentence contains contains tnm code T-1, N-O, M-1. This sentence contains tnm code T1N0M0. This sentence contains contains tnm code T1NOM1. This sentence is a sentence!?!?",

    "This sentence contains Dr. Seuss and no target words. This sentence contains Ms. Mary J. blige and no target words.",

    "This sentence contains the term stageIV and the word Breast. This sentence contains no target words.",

    "This sentence contains the word breast and the term metastatic. This sentence contains the word breast and the term stage IV."

  )), .Names = c("PTNO", "DATE", "TYPE", "TVAR"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Have you looked at the tidytext package?  It is much more friendly than the tm package.

Comment: Thanks lawyeR. Please see the partial solution I've added based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **quanteda** package is faster and more straightforward than **tm**, and works nicely with **tidytext** as well.  Here's how to do it:

These operations create a corpus from your object, create a document-feature matrix, and then return a data.frame that combines the variables with the feature counts.  (Additional options are available when creating the dfm, see `?dfm`).

```
library("quanteda")
samplecorp <- corpus(sampletxt, text_field = "TVAR")
sampledfm <- dfm(samplecorp)
result <- cbind(docvars(sampledfm), as.data.frame(sampledfm))
```

You can then group by the variables to get your result.  (Here I am showing just the first 6 columns.)

```
dplyr::group_by(result[, 1:6], PTNO, DATE, TYPE)
# # A tibble: 5 x 6
# # Groups:   PTNO, DATE, TYPE [5]
# PTNO       DATE          TYPE  this sentence contains
# * <dbl>     <date>         <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#     1     1 2016-01-01 Progress note     1        1        1
#     2     2 2015-01-01 Progress note     5        6        6
#     3     2 2015-01-01      CAT scan     2        2        2
#     4     3 2016-02-01 Progress note     2        2        2
#     5     3 2016-02-14 Progress note     2        2        2

packageVersion("quanteda")
# [1] ‘0.99.6’
```

Comment: Error in asMethod(object) : Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105

Comment: Absolutely terrific. Like magic. In fact, the last 4 letters of the name of your package "teda" remind me of the phrase "ta-dah!". Ran quite quickly on my actual data too. At least until the "result" cbind. There I get the error: Error in asMethod(object) : Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105. I looked it up and seems like I've simply run out of memory. There was also a note saying your package was using "16 out of 16 threads for parallel computing". I'm just starting to learn about big data. I was just wondering if there's something I could try.

Comment: Great! We just improved `cbind.dfm` yesterday... Try it after reinstalling using `devtools::install_github("kbenoit/quanteda")`. CRAN refresh imminent.

Comment: Reinstalled. Step still doesn't run. Result seems too large for my computing environment. I've got 217943 obs in a training dataset. I took a random sample of 500 rows and applied the code. That yields a DF with 29641 columns. Imagine the DF for all obs would be extremely large. Perhaps the trick would be to reduce the number of terms in the corpus before converting to DF. I want to classify on EGFR mutation status. So perhaps I could remove terms that are unlikely to be related to that before doing the conversion. Or perhaps the conversion is not strictly necessary to do the classification.

Comment: So the problem is no doubt that coercing the large (sparse) dfm to a dense data.frame creates an object that is too large. Better to work on the sparse matrix directly.

Answer (score 0):

this function from package "SentimentAnalysis" is the easiest way to do this, especially if you are trying to convert from column of a dataframe to DTM (though it also works on txt file!):

```
library("SentimentAnalysis")
corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(df$column_or_txt))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, 
                          control=list(wordLengths=c(1,Inf), 
                                       tokenize=function(x) ngram_tokenize(x, char=FALSE, 
                                                                           ngmin=1, ngmax=2)))
```

it is simple and works like a charm each time, with both chinese and english, for those doing text mining in chinese.